# Atomicity VS Synchronization using a mutex

Tags: multithreading, shared-memory, atomic

```
int a = 0;
```

Let's say we have 2 threads accessing a shared memory `a`;

`Atomicity` ensures every operation is `fully done` to every other thread. So if
I do `a = 5` every thread either sees `0` or `5` (and no other half updated 32 bit value).

Now here is my confusion. What If I want to ensure every other thread only sees `5` after the above assignment. The most popular way to accomplish this is use `locks` am I correct?

If so then `locks` don't provide atomicity? Atomicty and Synchronization are 2 different concepts?

Comment: The fact that lock provides synchronization doesn't exclude the fact that it also ensures the atomicity. And yes, they're different concepts - the atomicity is a property of a single operation while synchronization is a property of a sequence of operations.

Comment: You should include either one language tag, or the [tag:language-agnostic] tag.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually describing is yet another concept: visibility.

When you assign `a=5`, it takes a while until other CPUs see this assignment. If you want the assigning thread to not continue execution until all no other thread can see `a == 0`, and they can only see `a == 5`, then you need a [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

So to put order into these concepts:

#### Atomicity

Atomicity is the guarantee that no other thread sees partial or transient state changes, they only see consistent states.

On x86 (and some, but not all, other architectures), an assignment such as `a == 5` is guaranteed by the CPU to be atomic.

But if you have a struct with the state `{ a: 5, b: 10 }`, and that struct's invariant is that `b == a * 2`, in order to change the state, you need 2 assignments, which is not atomic. To make the state change atomic in this case, you'd need locks.

#### Locks

Locks allow you to implement a protocol among threads so that they wait until the state is consistent before accessing it.

In the example above, the way to implement it is `lock(mystruct); mystruct.a = myarg; mystruct.b = myarg * 2; unlock(mystruct);`. The goal of `lock(mystruct)` is to cause the thread to wait until the state of `mystruct` is consistent, thereby manually implementing atomicity.

#### Visibility

CPUs cache a lot of things. If the CPU had to write to main memory every time a variable is assigned, it would be thousands of times slower, at least.

Moreover, CPUs *reorder* instructions for optimal execution speed.

So assignments will *eventually* be visible to other threads, but are not immediately, and not in order.

If you want stronger guarantees, you need a memory barrier.

#### Memory Barriers

Look at the following code:

```
lock(mystruct);
mystruct.a = 9;
mystruct.b = 18;
unlock(mystruct);
// some thread might interleave here
lock(mystruct);
print(mystruct.a);
print(mystruct.b);
unlock(mystruct);
```

The CPU might say: "well, I just set `mystruct.a == 9`, so I can just print 9, I don't need to read `mystruct.a` from the main memory"

In order to prevent that, the implementation of `unlock(mystruct)` typically contains a memory barrier.

A memory barrier prevents the CPU from assuming that anything which happened before the barrier is still valid after the barrier, so when it needs to print `struct.a` it will fetch it from main memory.

#### Tying it together

Because the implementation of `unlock()` has a memory barrier, locks automatically guarantee not only atomicity, but also correct visibility.

Comment: Why would it take that long for another CPU to see the value? Which CPU exactly take that long?

Comment: That depends on the specific CPU implementation, but the general idea is that any CPU will cache whatever it can for as long as it possibly can, and will only consider the possibility that the value was modified by another CPU if explicitly told to consider it.

Comment: Which model specifically has a cache that keeps around stale data?

Comment: To my best understanding, all the modern ones. Detecting whether or not something is stale is expensive, so they let the programmers (well, libraries) decide when it's justified.

Comment: hi @root EXCELLENT ANSWER+1, it means that for a **update(change)** made by a thread on a global (shared) variable to be visible in other threads there has to be a memory barrier, e.g. a mutex, right? thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly. A memory barrier (e.g. mutex) guarantees visibility. Without it, the update will likely still be visible **eventually** - the CPU would flush its cached updates when it needs to make room in the cache for other updates.